# How to share Photos.app videos to YouTube directly?

Tags: photos.app, youtube, plugins

While it's great to have a quick upload to Vimeo (System Preferences app → Extensions → Share Menu) in Photos.app, what about a share extension to quickly upload videos from Photos to YouTube? Does such an extension exist that can be added to macOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag and drop directly from Photos to the upload page now.

It may seem like it's not working but just wait a little longer.

Comment: You're right, this works. You do have to wait a good long while though. Seems like Photos is exporting the movie into some temp file in the background before uploading that. The upload will "start" once that's done but is almost immediate then.

Answer (score 1):

While such an extension doesn't exist natively in macOS, the desired functionality can be added with the support of a 3rd party app.

[Video Uploader for YouTube](https://itunes.apple.com/app/video-uploader-for-youtube/id1111155003) is a macOS app which lets you easily upload your videos to YouTube.

The app also installs a Finder and Photos.app extension which lets you upload to YouTube directly from Finder or from within the Photos app.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could always import them into iMovie which allows sharing to YouTube.

- Start in iMovie and create a new project.
- Navigate to Media, you will see Photos as a Media source.
- After finding the clip, drag it to the editing area of iMovie.
- Share using share icon in the upper left, YouTube would be a selectable choice

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. If possible, it'd be good if you could add some more info on how users can use iMovie to import their Photos.app videos and share them to YouTube. Also, you may want to read [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for tips on providing answers here.